# Android : Old entries in file in SD card location not persist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to save data in a file in my SD card location.But the data saved to the file is not persistant and changes each time i enter new entries.
Only new entries showing up in file after adding entries and old entries just vanished.
What should i do to make data persist in the file.
Here is my .java code :

```
 package com.example.robin.userinputform;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;

 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

 public class UserActivity extends Activity {
 Button myButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);                       
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText myEdit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);            
            EditText myEdit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFatherName);
            EditText myEdit3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMobileNumber);
            try {
                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/MyApp.txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(myEdit1.getText());
                myOutWriter.append(myEdit2.getText());
                myOutWriter.append(myEdit3.getText());
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "file saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What you want is append new text to the file instead of over writing the old text or start with an empty file. You should open the stream in append mode with new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);.